# How to select and group date per 5 seconds interval?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd got a problem on selecting and grouping time
For example, I got the following time in database:

```
2014-03-31 00:00:06
2014-03-31 00:00:06
2014-03-31 00:00:06
2014-03-31 00:00:16
2014-03-31 00:00:16
2014-03-31 00:00:16
2014-03-31 00:00:22
2014-03-31 00:00:22
2014-03-31 00:00:22
2014-03-31 00:00:26
2014-03-31 00:00:26
2014-03-31 00:00:26
2014-03-31 00:00:39
2014-03-31 00:00:39
2014-03-31 00:00:39
2014-03-31 00:00:42
2014-03-31 00:00:42
2014-03-31 00:00:42
2014-03-31 00:00:49
2014-03-31 00:00:49
2014-03-31 00:00:49
2014-03-31 00:00:58
2014-03-31 00:00:58
2014-03-31 00:00:58
2014-03-31 00:01:30
2014-03-31 00:01:30
2014-03-31 00:01:30
2014-03-31 00:01:39
2014-03-31 00:01:39
2014-03-31 00:01:39
2014-03-31 00:01:40
2014-03-31 00:01:40
2014-03-31 00:01:40
2014-03-31 00:01:47
2014-03-31 00:01:47
2014-03-31 00:01:47
2014-03-31 00:02:06
2014-03-31 00:02:06
2014-03-31 00:02:06
2014-03-31 00:02:09
```

And I would like to group them in intervals of `5 seconds` and count them
Eg.

```
2014-03-31 00:00:00   Count 0
2014-03-31 00:00:05   Count 3
2014-03-31 00:00:10   Count 0
2014-03-31 00:00:15   Count 3
2014-03-31 00:00:20   Count 3
etc....
```

I've tried to use date_format and seems I cannot group them as expected.

Thanks all SOers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  select concat(date_format(dt,'%Y-%m-%d H:%i:'),lpad(floor(second(dt)/5)*5,2,'0')), count(*)
    from dates 
group by concat(date_format(dt,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:'),lpad(floor(second(dt)/5)*5,2,'0'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT   sec_to_time(time_to_sec(col1)- time_to_sec(col1)%(5)) AS timekey, count(*)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY timekey;
```

Fiddle example:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/27e02/4)